# Синхронизация mutex

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Нужно сделать синхронизацию с помощью мьютексов, но почему то пишет "индентификатор CloseHundle" не определен.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#pragma hdrstop
#pragma argsused
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HANDLE hMutex;
    wchar_t lpszAppName[] = L"C:\\ConsoleProcess.exe";
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    hMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, L"DemoMutex");
    if (hMutex == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Create mutex failed" << endl;
        cout << "Press any key to exit" << endl;
        cin.get();
        return GetLastError();
    }
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);

    if (!CreateProcess(lpszAppName, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
        cout << "The new process is not created" << endl;
        cout << "Press any key to exit" << endl;
        cin.get();
        return GetLastError();
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            cout << j << ' ' << flush;
            Sleep(10);
        }
        cout << endl;
        ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
    }
    CloseHundle(hMutex);
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHundle(pi.hThread);
    CloseHundle(pi.hProcess);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: нет, я никак не могу поверить, что это вопрос всерьез, а не приколоться...

Comment: невнимательность, она такая...

Answer (score 7):

CloseHundle не определен, потому что определен CloseHandle.